# Viewing Scrollviewer content in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, scrollviewer

I have come across this 'problem' a few times, but now start to wonder if there is an easier way to do this.

So, as per the screenshot, I have a WPF page with a Scrollviewer control. Is there a way to see the whole content of the Scrollviewer so I can actually see what I am editing inside the Scrollviewer? As you can see, half of the Scrollviewer is hidden from the editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is one workaround for this- setting a negative Top Margin to the child of the `ScrollViewer`.

Suppose you put a vertically stacked `StackPanel` inside the `ScrollViewer`, you can set a negative Top Margin (0, -N, 0, 0) to the `StackPanel` like this, so you can view the contents at the bottom at design time. Remember to remove the margin later.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Margin="0, -100, 0, 0">
        <!--Contents-->
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```